# Why does ITT drop drastically after startup?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-performance

Is this because of the increase of air that goes through the turbine that cools the parts?

Comment: I think you answered yourself 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the increase in airflow has a cooling effect.

Comment: Well that was easy!

Comment: Yep!  Yes or no questions are tough here because there is a 30 character minimum on answers.  But yeah, your hunch is correct.  Not much more really needs to be said.  (other than maybe thanks for the easy pitch...)